# React Protected Routes API calls

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a React protected route component that wraps around my routes to enable authentication on them. The protected route calls an API endpoint to check if the JWT stored in an HTTP Only cookie is valid. If so it renders the component associated with the requested route, if not it returns to the login page.

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import { UserContext } from '../functions/UserContext';

const ProtectedRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(0);
  const [gotResponse, setGotResponse] = useState(0);
  const { user, setUser } = useContext(UserContext);

  axios
    .post(
      process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL + '/api/auth/checkauth/',
      { content: 'checkAuthStatus' },
      {
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        withCredentials: true,
      }
    )
    .then((res) => {
      setUser(res.data.firstName + ' ' + res.data.lastName);
      setIsAuthenticated(1);
      setGotResponse(1);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      setIsAuthenticated(0);
      setGotResponse(1);
    });

  if (gotResponse === 1) {
    return (
      <Route
        {...rest}
        render={(props) => {
          if (isAuthenticated === 1) {
            return <Component {...rest} {...props} />;
          } else {
            return (
              <Redirect
                to={{
                  pathname: '/login',
                  state: {
                    from: props.location,
                  },
                }}
              />
            );
          }
        }}
      />
    );
  } else {
    return null;
  }
};

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

My main app.js file where most of the routing takes place looks like this;

```
function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState();

  return (
    <main>
      <Switch>
        <UserContext.Provider value={{ user, setUser }}>
          <Route
            exact
            path="/login"
            render={(props) => <Login {...props} />}
          ></Route>
          <ProtectedRoute
            exact
            path="/account"
            component={Account}
            title="Account"
          ></ProtectedRoute>
          <ProtectedRoute
            exact
            path="/staff"
            component={Staff}
          ></ProtectedRoute>
          <ProtectedRoute
            exact
            path="/security"
            component={Security}
          ></ProtectedRoute>
          <ProtectedRoute exact path="/" component={Home}></ProtectedRoute>

          <Route exact path="/2fa" component={Tfa}></Route>
        </UserContext.Provider>
        <Route component={NotFound}></Route>
      </Switch>
    </main>
  );
}

export default App;
```

When the app is running and I load up the login page or any of the other protected routes, I see numerous identical requests to the checkauth API endpoint.
[Chrome network tab screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kftbZ.png)

Is this because React is loading all my routes in a single chunk and hence calling the checkauth endpoint for every route on every page load? I'm a bit stumped.

TIA

Comment: EDIT - 
I figure it must be something to do with every route being rendered as when U change all my protected routes to regular routes except for the '/' home page route, the number of hits on the checkauth endpoint goes down to just 3 + 1 preflight. Though why there are still 3 rather than just 1 is still unclear to me

Comment: Call you checkAuth API in the main component. like in a top parent component. and store results in local storage or in a reducer (localStorage is preferred) then inside your protected route read the value from localStorage  and validate with it

Answer (score 0):

Thanks sojin for the tip. I moved the api call logic into my main app function like so;

```
function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState();
  const [authentication, setAuthentication] = useState({
    authenticated: false,
    initializing: true,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .post(
        process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL + '/api/auth/checkauth/',
        { content: 'checkAuthStatus' },
        {
          headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
          withCredentials: true,
        }
      )
      .then((res) => {
        setUser(res.data.firstName + ' ' + res.data.lastName);
        setAuthentication({
          authenticated: true,
          initializing: false,
        });
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        setAuthentication({
          authenticated: false,
          initializing: false,
        });
      });
  }, [setAuthentication]);

  if (authentication.initializing) {
    return <div>Loading</div>;
  }
  return (
    <main>
      <React.StrictMode>
        <Switch>
          <UserContext.Provider value={{ user, setUser }}>
            <Route
              exact
              path="/login"
              render={(props) => <Login {...props} />}
            ></Route>
            <ProtectedRoute
              exact
              path="/account"
              component={Account}
              title="Account"
              authenticated={authentication.authenticated}
            ></ProtectedRoute>
            <Route exact path="/staff" component={Staff}></Route>
            <ProtectedRoute
              exact
              path="/security"
              component={Security}
              authenticated={authentication.authenticated}
            ></ProtectedRoute>
            <ProtectedRoute
              exact
              path="/"
              component={Home}
              authenticated={authentication.authenticated}
            ></ProtectedRoute>

            <Route exact path="/2fa" component={Tfa}></Route>
          </UserContext.Provider>
          <Route component={NotFound}></Route>
        </Switch>
      </React.StrictMode>
    </main>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And tweaked the protected route like so;

```
const ProtectedRoute = ({ component: Component, authenticated, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) => {
        if (authenticated) {
          return <Component {...rest} {...props} />;
        } else {
          return (
            <Redirect
              to={{
                pathname: '/login',
                state: {
                  from: props.location,
                },
              }}
            />
          );
        }
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

I now only see the single instance of the checkauth endpoint being hit on each page load as I expected. Many thanks!

Comment: I don't think I have enough reputation to do that I'm afraid - sorry and thanks again